# Characteristic polynomial of triangular blocks matrix

Tags: block-matrices

Let A be a triangular blocks matrix (the blocks are: A1,...,Ak).
Show that CA(t)=CA1(t)*...*CAk(t).

Any help ? thanks ;)

(edit: CA and CAj are the characteristic polynomials of the blocks)

Comment: I don't get what $A$ is. Are you sure $A$ is supposed to be triangular?

Comment: If A is triangular, the proof is even simpler.  But as long as it is block diagonal the statement works.

Answer (score 0):

$$C(A)\equiv \det(A - tI)$$
Start from the theorem that determinant is multiplicative
$$ \det(KJ) = \det(K) \det(K)$$
Now consider any pair of 2-square-blocks square matrices 
$$ K ^{(N\times N)}=  \left( \begin{array}{cc} 
k^{r\times r} & 0^{r \times s} \\  0^{s \times r} & I^{s \times s}
\end{array} \right) $$
and 
$$ J ^{(N\times N)}=  \left( \begin{array}{cc} 
I^{r\times r} & 0^{r \times s} \\  0^{s \times r} & j^{s \times s}
\end{array} \right) $$
It is easy to see that 
$$
KJ = JK = 
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 
k^{r\times r} & 0^{r \times s} \\  0^{s \times r} & j^{s \times s}
\end{array} \right)
$$
By induction, it is then clear that the block diagonal matrix $A$ is product of matrices each containing one of the blocks of $A$ and 1's on the remainder of the diagonal. And $A-tI$ has that same structure
$$
A - tI = \prod_{i=1}^{k} \mbox{Block}_i (A_k - tI)
$$
and 
$$
C(A) = \det(A - tI)  = \prod_{i=1}^{k} \det \left(\mbox{Block}_i (A_k - tI) \right)
$$

But the determinant of each of the $mbox{Block}_i (A_k - tI) = \det((A_k - tI)$. And $\det((A_k - tI)$ is C(A_k).
So
$$ C(A) = \prod_{i=1}^{k} C(A_k)$$